# Get result of ffmpeg and pass it to a python script

Tags: python, linux, ffmpeg

Pretty sure this is doable but I am not exactly sure on how to achieve it.

I have a Raspberry Pi streaming constantly on my local network and I use this `ffmpeg` script to save the video inside the Pi.

```
ffmpeg -i http://0.0.0.0:8080/stream/video.mjpeg -vcodec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 5 -segment_format mp4 capture-%05d.mp4
```

The script is rather straightforward, it loads and saves 5 seconds video continuously in a local directory.

[image]

Here's what I am trying to do ultimately

> Upload all saved videos to a Cloud Storage, then delete the local copy

I tried to pipe the output of `ffmpeg` to a python script like this but it does not work the way I imagine it would.

```
ffmpeg -i http://0.0.0.0:8080/stream/video.mjpeg -vcodec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 5 -segment_format mp4 capture-%05d.mp4 | py test.py -p capture-%05d.mp4
```

This is my script, just to get the name/path of video

```
import argparse

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--videoPath', type=str, help="Path to recorded video", required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    print(args.videoPath)
```

Comment: Do you want the output of the `ffmpeg` command as a string in python?

Comment: I prefer the output as a string (file name). For example, capture-00001.mp4.

Comment: So basically you want to copy over the newly created files to a cloud storage? One way could be having the `ffmpeg` running as a separate process and then using `inotify` module in python to know when a new file is written fully to the disk.

Comment: The other way could be, calling the `ffmpeg` command from the python and then capture it's stdout and then process that output in near realtime and then get the required data from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking into the man page of `ffmpeg` and came across the loglevel option.

```
-loglevel [repeat+]loglevel | -v [repeat+]loglevel
       Set the logging level used by the library.  Adding "repeat+" indicates that repeated log output should not be compressed to the first line and the "Last message repeated n
       times" line will be omitted. "repeat" can also be used alone.  If "repeat" is used alone, and with no prior loglevel set, the default loglevel will be used. If multiple
       loglevel parameters are given, using 'repeat' will not change the loglevel.  loglevel is a string or a number containing one of the following values:

       verbose, 40
           Same as "info", except more verbose.
```

So here is a simple one-liner workaround to get the things working in your case -

```
ffmpeg -i my_vid_feed -vcodec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 5 -loglevel 40 -segment_format mp4 capture-%05d.mp4 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered -Eo "segment:.+ended" | awk -F "'" '{print $2; system("")}' | xargs -n1 python my_processor.py -p
```

I am just parsing the output of the `ffmpeg`, when a new file is written completely the verbose log emits a line like this -

```
[segment @ 0x7fc253817000] segment:'capture-00002.mp4' count:2 ended
```

So I am just taking the filename from the line and passing it to that argparse python file. The `-n1` option in the `xargs` tells it to only pass one arg at a time to the python file and then execute the python script with that file as an argument.
Here is the output of the command in action -

```
root$ ffmpeg -i my_vid_feed -vcodec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 5 -loglevel 40 -segment_format mp4 capture-%05d.mp4 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered -Eo "segment:.+ended" | awk -F "'" '{print $2; system("")}' | xargs -n1 python my_processor.py -p
started
capture-00000.mp4
ended
started
capture-00001.mp4
ended
started
capture-00002.mp4
ended
started
capture-00003.mp4
ended
```

The python file used - my_processor.py

```
import argparse
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--videoPath', type=str, help="Path to recorded video", required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print("started")
    print(args.videoPath)
    time.sleep(3)
    print("ended")
```

The only possible drawback to this would be at a time there will be only one instance of python running and your jobs would run sequentially after the previous job is done. In case you want to run them in parallel, you can do that as well.

Comment: Excellence! You definitely understood my doubts! Appreciate the effort, but when I try to run those options, videos are saved but xargs does not seem to work. I monitored the processes and saw that xargs and python are running but there is simply no output

Comment: ahh, that must be the `awk` buffering and waiting for the buffer to fill completely before execution. Can you just change the awk to `awk -F "'" '{print $2; system("")}'`? That should work.

Comment: It still prints nothing. Here's my latest command. `ffmpeg -i http://0.0.0.0:8080/stream/video.mjpeg -vcodec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 5 -loglevel 40 -segment_format mp4 capture-%05d.mp4 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered -Eo "segment:.+ended" | awk -F "'" '{print $2; system("")}' | xargs -n1 python3.6 test.py -p`

Comment: ohh, can you try this and see if you are getting any output `ffmpeg -i http://0.0.0.0:8080/stream/video.mjpeg -vcodec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 5 -loglevel 40 -segment_format mp4 capture-%05d.mp4 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered -Eo "segment:.+ended"`

Comment: I am able to get `segment:'capture-00000.mp4' count:0 ended`, and the subsequent frames

Comment: Are you also able to get only the filenames after you also add the `awk` part to the above command?

Comment: Unfortunately no, even with both your awk suggestions :(

Comment: `$ ffmpeg -i my_vid_feed -vcodec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 5 -loglevel 40 -segment_format mp4 capture-%05d.mp4 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered -Eo "segment:.+ended" | awk -F "'" '{print $2; system("")}'`
output - 
`capture-00000.mp4
capture-00001.mp4
capture-00002.mp4`
I am able to see the filenames in real time though as and when they keep coming, and they are not buffering for me. Which platform are you on?

Comment: I am running this on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B. armv7l. Raspbian GNU/Linux 8

Comment: Can you check the version of awk? I guess the awk version is very old on Pi 3, can you try `gawk` instead or upgrade the `awk` to a newer version.

Comment: Thank you! It was awk that causes the trouble! I've installed gawk and now I'm seeing the file names!

Comment: np, so now the whole pipeline including the python part should start working as intended.

Comment: Yes indeed! Now I will have to figure out a way to upload the videos to my cloud storage. And I am expecting the drawback you mentioned in the answer. I think this method could potentially bloat my Pi to death because essentially it tries to call a new python instance every time it saves a video. Do you have a better way to approach this?

Comment: Yep, but at a given time, there would be only one python process running at a time. The other option can be running the `ffmpeg` process from python itself and then processing it's output in python and then upload them to the cloud. But then you will have to manage a lot of edge cases and concurrency/async/timeouts for uploads. Another option could be the `inotify` in conjunction with multiprocessing. `inotify` is basically a system hook which tells you if there are new files are created in a given directory and then process those newly created files in parallel if you want.

Comment: I have tried the first option. I managed to spawn a number of threads to handle all the requests at once. But there comes a time where the processes are bound by I/O and network traffic, hence it would tremendously delay my latter algorithms. Will give second approach a try.

Comment: Yep, the concurrency should be always be limited and controllable in the approaches. You can do that with either approach. Like for the first approach, 3-4 parallel threads should be ok(you can do some benchmarks and decide on what works best for you in terms of I/O and resource utilization). Also, you can probably also add some timeouts/retries in case the request fails in order to make the utility more robust.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts. Thanks for your effort in answering my doubts.

Comment: np, happy to help! :)